# why i can't pass parameters to flash using 'file://' protocol?

Tags: linux, flash, parameters

**system info**
flash player version: 10_1_102_65
OS: linux debian, 6.0.2
web browser: Mozilla Iceweasel 3.5.16

**problem description**
I have a flash file that uses parameters to show output on the screen. unfortunately i don't have sources and can't modify/review it.

i can successfully run flash and pass parameters to it using http:// protocol. for example,
#> iceweasel http:///localhost/40.swf?channel_id=1
shows correct flash in the browser.

but when i try to load flash from file
#> iceweasel file:///home/user/40.swf?channel_id=1
flash can't read passed parameter and shows invalid output

it's really strange. because when i downgraded flash plugin (from 10_1_102_65 to 9) both protocols works! That is something occurred in the flash player above 9.
unfortunately i can't use Flash Player 9 in my production environment so i should resolve the issue with Flash Player 10.

**question**
how can i pass parameters to flash using 'file://' protocol?

any help is appreciated. 
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ignacio says, GET parameters are part of HTTP and won't work with the file:// protocol, but one thing you could try is to supply the channel_id is a a [FlashVar](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html). Internally in the swf, the ActionScript code normally access GET parameters and FlashVars the same way (using loaderInfo.parameters).

Comment: how can you explain that flash player 9 works with both protocols?

Comment: I can't. But I think you have good chances of making it work using FlashVars, regardless of Flash Player version.

Comment: oh, i didn't pay attention to acceptance. thanks for info. will take it into account.

Comment: by the way. i've tried to add flashvars param to <embed> tag and that didn't help me. maybe something wrong in my environment and flash player doesn't want to play correctly. i've tried following code:<embed
    id="flash_id"
    src="file:///home/users/40.swf"
    flashvars="channel_id=1"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
</embed>

Comment: That embed code incl. flashvars looks correct. I really can't say why  that wouldn't work. Except that when a '<object>' tag is used, it may require a separate '<param name="flashvars" value="channel_id=1" />' as a sub element.

Answer (score 2):

GET only exists in HTTP. You cannot use a query string when accessing a local file. And since you don't have the source, it's near impossible to provide an alternative.

Comment: thanks for help but i can't agree with you. i've added some information about flash player 9. sorry that I didn't provide it in my first post.